# Invariant subfield of $\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $G$ be the group of automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}$ defind by $G=\{T\mapsto T+\xi\mid\xi\in\mathbb F_q\}$. Can one describe ${\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}}^G$?

Comment: Can one describe $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q(T)}$?

Comment: $T\mapsto T+\xi$ does not uniquely determine an automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}$. Could you clarify what you mean?